# How to reproduce this effect and what's its name?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, images, interface-design, 3d

I have been looking on project on behance and there are plenty of projects that show interfaces in a 3d way with depth and I can't find anything to reproduce something like this, so since I am not a native speaker I am wondering if I use the wrong terms.

This is what I am talking about :
[image: 3d interface]

Or another example : 
[image]

Sometimes it is even like on a phone : 
[image]

So you get the idea.
Do you know what is the name of this ?
When I search I always fall into google material design elevation thing which is not really what I am looking for.
Do you have any links or tutorial on how to do this type of effect please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is called a mockup or product mockup.

There are numerous sites offering both [free](https://mrmockup.com/freebies/) and [paid](https://creativemarket.com/graphics/product-mockups) options.

The ones you specifically posted are website and phone mockups which are **isometric**. This has become a trend lately and are being used more often.

Comment: Yes this is it, it is so much easier when you know the terms, thank you! Was it obvious if you are a native english speaker or did it require knowledge in design ?

Comment: Both help - it's become commonplace in the US in interface and graphic design to do these kind of mockups: isometrics are easy to achieve within most design software, and so are most used; it's also comparatively easy to produce perspective views much the same way, and some people (me included) also will bring designs into 3D DCC tools and do photoreal perspective renders of design intent output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxukI.jpg

Comment: @rn605435 Just a note here. Yes if you were a native English speaker, the word "mock-up" is pretty common. It has been around at least since the 1920's according to the OED, in the sense of  replica/model of something.  It's not only used in graphic design - it can be a replica/model of anything.